# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) C++ error, pointer related

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

From what I understand so far; the issue I'm having is likely pointer related. I am relatively new to C++ and while I think I know where the problem is occurring, I am having trouble understanding why it is occurring.

Below is the constructor for a linked list of nodes that store a string (called "data") each and I want to have a method I can call on a linked list (initialized in main) that eventually prints out the contents of each node. I started by just attempting to print the contents of the first node (which is pointed to by root) but then ran into the segmentation fault error. I have been fiddling with my code and looking up online resources for hours to no avail. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "Linked.h"


Linked::Linked(int size){

    Node *root;         //the start of the linked list, remains static
    root = new Node;   // sets it to point at a Node   
    Node *conductor;  // This will point to each node as it traverses the list
    conductor = root; // The conductor points to the first node

    if ( conductor != 0 ) {
        while ( conductor->next != 0)
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        //std::cout << conductor->data;
        conductor->next = new Node;  // Creates a node at the end of the list
        conductor = conductor->next; // Points to that node
    }
}
void Linked::printMemory(){
int memorycheck[32] = { }; // 
Node *conductor; //creates a conductor
conductor = root; //sets conductor to point to the same Node that root does, the issue may occur here. Why?

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    std::cout << conductor->data; 


}
```

This is my header file for Linked
}

```
#ifndef LINKED
#define LINKED
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"


 class Linked {
 public:
     Node *root;
     Linked(int size);
     void addProgram (std::string name, int size);
     void printMemory ();


};
 #endif
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `Node *root; //the start of the linked list, remains static` This is a **BIG** misconception! Your member variable for `root` is shadowed by the local pointer definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Basile. Utilizing GDB returns this: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000003ff734790 in cygstdc++-6!_ZStlsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES7_RK                            SbIS4_S5_T1_E () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
                                                                      (I'm afraid that I don't grasp the implications of this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinnk you have a problem in you constructor.

```
Linked::Linked(int size){

    Node *root;         //the start of the linked list, remains static
    ...
}
```

Here you declare a variable `root`, and this is not the same `root` in your class definition! Try to remove this line from your code.

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I didn't catch that, I wrote the header after building a bit of the Linked class and that must have been left over. Thank you so much! Sorry for wasting your time everyone.